# JavaFX - TableView - Keep Position in List After Applying Predicate

Tags: javafx

General question from someone relatively new to JavaFX.  I'm sure there has to be a simple solution.  I have a large observable list (10,000 items).  I'm wrapping that as a FilteredList and using it in a Tableview.  When a button is clicked, I apply a predicate that hides a portion of the items - maybe every third item.  When clicked again, the predicate is cleared.

My issue is this.  The user pages through the Tableview/FilteredList to item 500.  The item doesn't have focus and isn't selected but is the first item shown in the view.  They click the button and one-third of the items are hidden.  The tableview is redisplaced starting at the 500th item in the FilteredList - much deeper in the list.

I would like the list to redisplay showing the approximate location from before predicate was applied.  For example, if item 500 was not removed by the filter, I would like it to be the first item show after the redisplay.  If it was filtered, then I would like item 501 to be the first item redisplayed.  In essence, I would like the items showing that are not filtered before the predicate is applied to show after the predicate is applied.  If it’s displaying the following before:

500

501

502

503

504

and 500 and 502 are filtered, I want it to display

501

503

504

505

506

Not the following

710

711

712

713

714

I hope that makes sense.  I don't need a complete example of how to do this but I sure could use someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: You had me up until the 710-714 sub-list - which i'm assuming is pagination based. Could you update the question with some additional info?

Comment: Thanks Peter.  I'm not using pagination.  I think I found a somewhat ugly way to do this.  I've added a row factory and overloaded the updateItem method.  I save a reference to the item referenced in the last row updated.  With that, I can locate the right position (matching object or next after based on a control number in the object) in the tableView after the filter is applied and scroll to that location.  Not pretty but it works.